# Use $_GET in iframe on another website

Tags: php, html, iframe, get

I am using a website (1st) to show another website (2nd) in a `iframe`.

On the first website, I am using `$_GET` variables within the link:

`http://mywebsite.co.uk/page.php?id=1&ref=2`

I am trying to figure out a way to use these variables on the second website while displayed within this `iframe` on the `page.php`?

At the moment I have tried using this code on the Second website:

```
if(isset($_GET['ref'])){
$website_ref_code = $_GET['ref'];
} 
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
$website_id_code = $_GET['id'];
}
```

Although this is returning no data within the variables?

First of all, I am wondering if this is at all possible? If so, how is the right way to do this?

Comment: are they on the same domain?

Comment: No different domains

Comment: Does the `src` part in the iframe tags also has `?id=1&ref=2` ?

Comment: No, but I could update that if you think that would help?

Comment: thats the best and a save way to do that without to use `top.window.location`(js) or `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` (php) in the iframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind changing the exact URL that the `iframe` requests, you can reuse Website 1's GET parameters in the `src` of the Website 2 `iframe`. So in your example, the user navigates to this page on Website 1:

```
http://example1.com/page.php?id=1&ref=2
```

You can then use the PHP on Website 1 to dynamically construct an `iframe` that looks like this:

```
<iframe src="http://example2.com/page.php?id=1&ref=2"></iframe>
```

That way you will have access to the same GET parameters from within the `iframe`, on Website 2.

Comment: This seems to be working nicely for me, I appreciate the help! Will this work with two totally different domains?

Comment: @Snappysites It will, since the GET parameters are simply passed through in the URL!